# Repeating an HTML snippet that contains elements with id attribute defined

Tags: html, iframe

I need to repeat an html snippet several times on a page but the problem is that the contained html elements have `id` defined that should be unique on page. So what is the proper way I could repeat this snippet without removing the `id` attribute from the elements ?

**Could I use iframe as container for this snippet & let the duplicate ids exist on page?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to clone the snippet and at the same time change the IDs.

Example if your snippet is:

```
<div id="snippet">
   <table id="list">
    <tr id="0">
      <td id="firstName0">John</td>
      <td id="lastName0">Smith</td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="1">
      <td id="firstName2">John</td>
      <td id="lastName2">Doe</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Using

```
$("#snippet").clone(false).find("*[id]").andSelf().each(function() { $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id") + "_1"); });
```

Will Produce

```
<div id="snippet_1">
   <table id="list_1">
    <tr id="0_1">
      <td id="firstName0_1">John</td>
      <td id="lastName0_1">Smith</td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="1_1">
      <td id="firstName2_1">John</td>
      <td id="lastName2_1">Doe</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Which will solve the duplicate ID problem.

Comment: but I also have javascript in between the html like within onclick or onkeyup that refers to the elements using ids. Changing  ids this way is probably not a solution for me..